# QT DataGrid with Grouped Rows

Tags: datagridview, qt4

I am writing an application with data grid and I want something similar to ExtJS GroupingView.
Is there something like that coded already ? 
I have seen QTitan DataGrid but it is not free and not opensource.
Thanks.!

ExjJS grid looks like this:

[ExjJS grid image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3pxo.png)

Comment: What does an ExtJS GroupingView or a QTitan DataGrid look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevExpress (http://devexpress.com) have I believe one of the best Grids with Grouping support. QTitan's (http://www.devmachines.com) is a replica of the DevExpress one.

DevExpress have their grids for C#, Delphi, VB.NET, as ActiveX. You haven't really specified which language you use.